# If $\sup(f+g)\le \sup \ f + \sup \ g$, then why $\underline\int_{A}f(x)\ dx + \underline\int_{A}g(x)\ dx \le \underline\int_{A}[f(x) + g(x)]\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If $\sup(f+g)\le \sup \ f + \sup \ g$, then why

$$\underline\int_{A}f(x)\ dx + \underline\int_{A}g(x)\ dx \le \underline\int_{A}[f(x) + g(x)]\ dx$$

?
I already asked a similar question here: [Prove that $\underline{\int_A}{f(x) \ dx} + \underline{\int_A}{g(x) \ dx} \le \underline{\int_A}{[f(x) + g(x)] \ dx}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462113/prove-that-underline-int-afx-dx-underline-int-agx-dx-le-u) and a proof was presented. But it seems to disagree with the formula for the sup of a sum: [Sum of the supremum and supremum of a sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564360/sum-of-the-supremum-and-supremum-of-a-sum)

What's wrong?

Comment: Where is the disagreement with the lower integral inequality which is correct, and a property of the supremum? Why would you not provide feedback or ask for clarification in the previously posted question/answer?

Comment: @RRL because the proof he gave seems correct. The disagreement is that in one side, the sup is greater than the sum of the sups, while in the other side, not